# Use boxslider in Magento 2 in custom module

Tags: magento-2.1, module, jquery

I am trying to use `boxslider` in my custom module.

**NOTE:** I am in developer mode

> **UPDATE :** In `network`, i saw that files are loaded as

1) `require.js`

2) `requirejs-config.js` ( at top my require codes are mentioned )

3) `jquery.js`

Is it the normal flow of `Magento 2` or I am doing something wrong in my custom module that's why it's loaded first.

At `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/NameSpace/ReviewRating/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
 var config = {

// main.min is used for custom js where I handle some other things so I need this js file as well.
        deps: [
            "NameSpace_ReviewRating/js/main.min"
        ],

          shim: {
            "boxslider": ["jquery"]

        },


         map: {
            '*': {
                'boxslider': 'NameSpace_ReviewRating/js/boxslider/jquery.bxslider'
            }
        }

    };
```

At `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/NameSpace/ReviewRating/view/frontend/templates/homeverticalwidget.phtml`

```
<script>
{
require([
        'jquery',
         "boxslider"
        ], function () {
            'use strict';
            jQuery.noConflict();
                jQuery(function () {

                     jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                        mode: 'vertical',
                        captions: true,
                        slideWidth: 600,
                        minSlides: 3,
                        maxSlides: 3,
                        moveSlides: 2,
                        slideWidth: 200

                     });        


        });

    });

}   
</script>
```

**Isuues : IN console**
1) `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` ( in console this points to slider core js file )

I am not able to figure it out where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing require function arguments which will be returning be require.js for each js you are calling. So your script should be like this:

```
require([ 'jquery', "boxslider" ], function (jQuery) {
 //...your code here now you can access jQuery
});
```

As you already have **shim** for jQuery for your boxslider so you don't need to specify function argument for boxslider after jQuery, that's why I have only passed jQuery as function argument.

Comment: i tired by updating in ` homeverticalwidget.phtml` still same issue in console

Comment: i am passing boxslider already to require i think

Answer (score 0):

Try this Now

> app/code/NameSpace/ReviewRating/view/frontend/templates/homeverticalwidget.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery','bxsliderjs'],function($,bxSlider){
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'vertical',
            captions: true,
            slideWidth: 600,
            minSlides: 3,
            maxSlides: 3,
            moveSlides: 2,
            slideWidth: 200
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code :**

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "boxslider": "'NameSpace_ReviewRating/js/boxslider/jquery.bxslider'"
        }
    }
};
```

**homeverticalwidget.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //function for load owlcarousel slider
    require([ 'jquery', 'boxslider'], function(jQuery){

        jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                        mode: 'vertical',
                        captions: true,
                        slideWidth: 600,
                        minSlides: 3,
                        maxSlides: 3,
                        moveSlides: 2
        }); 


     });

</script>
```

Remove **pub/static directory** and **run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy** command

Also clear cache by running **php bin/magento cache:clean** and **php bin/magento cache:flush** command.

**UPDATE :**

Open your **bxslider.js** file and put below code at the beginning of the js.

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function () {

**your bx slider js code here**

});
```

Comment: Sir , i tried your suggestion as well and i am in developer mode , still deployed but no success

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan okay got your problem  - I have updated my answer please check just update your bxslider.js file and check it works

Comment: sir i updated my question can you please see whats the issue

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan - its work fine here at my end with the code i have posted , so try with that and let me know if its works or not